# can't get a view controller property to another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

i have 2 view controllers:

StackTableViewController.m:

```
@interface StackTableViewController () <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultController;

@end

@implementation StackTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.fetchedResultController performFetch:nil];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0];
    Target *record = [self.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    self.currentTarget = record.body;
}
```

HomeViewController.m

```
#import "HomeViewController.h"
#import "CreateViewController.h"
#import "StackTableViewController.h"

@interface HomeViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *targetLabel;

@end

@implementation HomeViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    StackTableViewController *vc = [[StackTableViewController alloc] init];
    NSString *current = vc.currentTarget;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.targetLabel.text = current;
}
```

but something wrong with the HomeViewController because it's not populating the label..

how can i solve it?

tnx

Answer (score 0):

You should probably update the label's text within ViewWillAppear of the StackTableViewController

Also, is currentTarget set up in StackTableViewController's init method? If not, it won't be initialized and that would be why you're not getting anything in HomeViewController's label

Comment: What do you mean by "the init method" in stack iewconteoller?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html

Comment: i have an nesting property in the StackTableViewController.h that i want to use to pass this data to the second view controller

Answer (score 0):

## Explanation

`viewDidLoad` is not called instead, or before the `init`! It's called sometime **after** the `init` method finishes.

**What happens:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   StackTableViewController *vc = [[StackTableViewController alloc] init]; // init is called on vc object
   NSString *current = vc.currentTarget; // ViewDidLoad was not yet called on vc object!
   self.targetLabel.text = current;
}
/// ViewDidLoad will be called on vc object sometime after leaving this method!
```

What happens is:
You call `StackTableViewController *vc = [[StackTableViewController alloc] init];` which sends a message `init` to the object.
You don't have `init` method in your implementation so the `init` of superclass (`UIViewController`) is called. When you instantiate your `ViewController` it begins loading view. Only after it's done loading `ViewDidLoad` will be called.

Please read any article on `ViewController`'s [lifecycle](https://medium.com/@SergiGracia/ios-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle-261e3e2f6133) .

## Solution

Fastest solution to your problem: create a delegate in your table, and inform when it's done loading using delegates, like this:

**Table view controller**

```
@implementation StackTableViewController
{
    id<TargetChangedDelegate> _myDelegate;
}
-(id)initWithDelegate:(id<TargetChangedDelegate>)delegate
{
    _myDelegate= delegate;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.fetchedResultController performFetch:nil];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0];
    Target *record = [self.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    self.currentTarget = record.body;

    // inform your delegate
    [_myDelegate targetChanged];

}
```

**Home view controller**

```
@interface HomeViewController () <TargetChangedDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *targetLabel;

@end

@implementation HomeViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    StackTableViewController *vc = [[StackTableViewController alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
}

- (void)targetChanged
{
    NSString *current = vc.currentTarget;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
   self.targetLabel.text = current;
}
```